# individual contacts: Bulk email?

Tags: civimail

What does it mean if, on an individual contact, I select the 'bulk email?' box when editing their email address?

I want to be sure that all of our contacts can receive our newsletter.

Answer (score 2):

If you set a bulk email address it will be used instead of the primary email address to send your newsletters to. You may even set more than one email adress as bulk email address.